# Jenkins and gradle artifactory integration -- authentication

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I am not clear on how I can publish from a *Jenkins* server to *Artifactory* without committing my credentials in `gradle`.properties.  I have been reading over the wiki and forums, but nothing seems to address this (or I missed it).

We have a shared *Jenkins* server and my project uses `gradle`.  I would like to deploy to my artifacts to a specific repo (linked to my *artifactory* logon account) on *artifactory*.   I can deploy using my local machine, since I have my artifactory_user, *artifactory* password, and *artifactory* contextUrl values set in `gradle`.properties.

Without committing my *artifactory* credentials, how do I deploy from our Jenkins server?

I thought I could use the Gradle-Artifactory integration plugin and use the "Override default deployer credentials" option to specify my credentials on the Jenkins UI and it would override (or set) my *Artifactory* username and password, but that does not appear to work.

I always get the error in my build:

```
15:36:52 A problem occurred evaluating root project 'TCS-master-CI'.
15:36:52 Could not find property 'artifactory_user' on root project 'TCS-master-CI'
```

.

So what does the `Gradle` *Artifactory* Integration provide me?  Is there something in the build code I need to do to make this work correctly?

Do I need to specify the `gradle`.properties somewhere on the shared Jenkins Server?

I would appreciate anybodys help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you can publish from a Jenkins server to Artifactory without committing the credentials in gradle.properties:

```
artifactory {
  publish {
    repository {
      username = project.hasProperty('artifactory_user') ? project.artifactory_user : System.getenv()['ARTIFACTORY_USER']
      password = project.hasProperty('artifactory_password') ? project.artifactory_password, : System.getenv()['ARTIFACTORY_KEY']
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It clarifies how one can publish from a Jenkins server to Artifactory without committing the credentials in gradle.properties.

Comment: Yes, so put that in your answer for future searchers of the issue. (I only mention this because your post came through the low quality review queue so trying to clean it up).